# Partial correlation values are larger than normal correlation in R

Tags: r, correlation, pearson-correlation

I am working on a large dataset (7 million rows) trying to understand the correlations between individual independent variables with dependent variables. When I run pcor(dataset) this results in higher correlations if compared when running cor(dataset).

My dataset has 6 dependent variables and 84 independent variables. I am finding the partial correlation for **each** dependent variable along with the 84 independent variables individually.

My independent variables are word counts for text type(75 categories), and some other social variables (all numerical) etc. gender.

My question is: I am not sure why I am getting high correlations when using pcor() in R and very weak correlation using cor(). Is this normal behavior for partial correlation?

Comment: `pcor` is not a base R function. Which package does `pcor` belong to and what does it do?

Comment: Google tells me that `pcor` is part of packages `ppcor`, `RVAideMemoire` and `ggm`; which one did you use? Furthermore, in partial correlation you are measuring the correlation between two variables while controlling for additional confounding variables. Obviously this will give you different results than if you use `cor`.

Comment: There's no general ordering between the correlation and the partial correlation. Take e.g. `x=rnorm(10000)`, `y=rnorm(10000)` and `z=(x+y)/2`. Then `cor(x,y)` is almost zero, while `pcor(x,y|z)` is positive. The other ordering is possible too.

Comment: I am using ppcor package in R

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're wondering whether a partial correlation coefficient can be *larger* than a "full" correlation coefficient, consider the following example.

Let's take a look at the sample data from the [`ppcor` reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ppcor/)

```
df <- data.frame(
    hl = c(7,15,19,15,21,22,57,15,20,18),
    disp = c(0.000,0.964,0.000,0.000,0.921,0.000,0.000,1.006,0.000,1.011),
    deg = c(9,2,3,4,1,3,1,3,6,1),
    BC = c(1.78e-02,1.05e-06,1.37e-05,7.18e-03,0.00e+00,0.00e+00,0.00e+00 ,4.48e-03,2.10e-06,0.00e+00))
```

According to the original paper, the data cover the relationship between sequence and functional evolution in yeast proteins, and is available from [[Drummond et al., Molecular Biology and Evolution 23, 327–337 (2006)]](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16237209).

We are interested in exploring the correlation between `hl` and `disp`.

### Linear relationship between `hl` and `disp`

Let's start by plotting `hl` as a function of `disp`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(hl, disp)) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]

The standard ("full") Pearson's product moment correlation coefficient is given by

```
with(df, cor(hl, disp))
#[1] -0.2378724
```

As is obvious from the plot and `cor` results, without controlling for any other variable, the linear relationship between `hl` on `disp` is not very strong.

### Partial correlation

To recap the definition: Partial correlation between X and Y given confounding variables Z is defined as the correlation of the residuals resulting from a linear regression of X on Z an Y on Z.

Let's visualise the partial correlation by plotting the residuals of the two corresponding linear models  `hl ~ deg + BC` and `disp ~ deg + BC`.

```
ggplot(data.frame(
    res.x = lm(hl ~ deg + BC, df)$residuals, 
    res.y = lm(disp ~ deg + BC, df)$residuals)) +
    geom_point(aes(res.x, res.y))
```

[image]

The linear dependence of both residuals is very obvious, suggesting a significant partial correlation between `hl` and `disp`. Let's confirm by calculating the partial correlation between `hl` and `disp` whilst controlling for confounding effects from `deg` and `BC`

```
pcor.test(df$hl, df$disp, df[, c("deg","BC")])
#    estimate    p.value statistic  n gp  Method
#1 -0.6720863 0.06789202 -2.223267 10  2 pearson
```

### Conclusion

Pearson's product moment correlation coefficient between `hl` and `disp` is larger when we control for confounding variables, than the correlation coefficient when we do *not* control for confounders.

Comment: Is it normal for a partial correlation pcor() to have a different sign than a standard cor()? I get a positive correlation when I run pcor(A, B | Other_variables) but negative correlation when running cor(A, B)  (for the same two variables) @Maurits

Comment: @AKD Yes, that can absolutely happen. I would consider that an example of [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox). For more details, perhaps also take a look at the interesting (and related) post on Cross Validated: [Regression coefficients that flip sign after including other predictors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1580/regression-coefficients-that-flip-sign-after-including-other-predictors).